# Powershell rename using variable

Tags: powershell, rename

Hi am not able to rename a file using the below code. Please help me on this

```
    $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
    $path='D:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\'
    $fn = $path+'xxx_'+$date+'.txt'
    $tn = $path+'yyy'+$date+'.dat'
    Rename-Item -Path $fn -NewName $tn
```

Am getting the below error.

> Rename-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the
>   "path" argument and run the operation again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Rename-Item -Path $fn -NewName $tn
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: the file exist?

Comment: Right before the rename, do this `Write-Host ('$fn = {0} - $tn = {1}' -f $fn, $tn)`

Comment: Please update your question with the result of the instruction in EBGreen's comment.

Comment: Try `Remove-Variable path` prior to defining path, in case something is casting `$path` to something besides a `[string]`. I had some code in my profile caused some similar issues by not cleaning up the `$path` variable. Using alternative methods of building the string like LotPings solution work by verifying that `$path` is of the expected type before use. (LotPings answer even has some extra validation to validate the path prior to use)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Join-Path and Test-Path

```
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
$path='D:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\'
$fn = Join-Path $path ("xxx_{0}.txt" -f $date)
$tn = Join-Path $path ("yyy_{0}.txt" -f $date)
If ((Test-Path $fn) -and !(Test-Path $tn)){
    Rename-Item -Path $fn -NewName $tn
} else {
    "{0} exists is {1}, `n{2} not exists is {3}" -f $fn,(Test-Path $fn),$tn,(!(Test-Path $tn))
}
```

There is no output on a successful rename, on error the output is like:

```
D:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\xxx_20180606.txt exists is False,
D:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\yyy_20180606.txt not exists is False
```

Comment: I ***love*** such precise feed back :-( there were a pair of parentheses missing changed above

Comment: Not working how? There is an error? The file is accidentally being copied to Pluto? Wombats keep licking the spaces between your toes and it tickles? There is even a minimun limit on comment size so that people don't bother with worthless comments like "Not working".

Comment: Even without the checks, the error is `Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Working\xxx_20180606.txt' does not exist.` which doesn't match with the one in the question.

Comment: @pfx See BenH's comment, my method of building the file name with the `-format` operator prevents mistreating `$fn` as a string array.

Comment: @LotPings I understand, but I get `TypeName: System.String` for `$fn | Get-Member` (same for `$tn`) followed by the does-not-exist error. `$fn` as in OP's question.

Comment: @pfx What output do you get with the actual script verson? I presume you use pathes/files matching your environment.

Comment: @LotPings `System.String`; I always worked with the original script ... kinda lazy :). Ran it via PS ISE and .ps1 file, using PS: 5.1.16299.431, Win10 64bit: 1709 16299.431.

Comment: You should ask yuor own question then, equipped with sufficient details.

Comment: I lost track of the conversation. $fn is saying it is a string and the -Path property of Rename-Item takes a string. I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @EBGreen I can't reproduce that `$fn` in OP's question is an array on which to apply to solution above.

Comment: Nothing that I have seen anywhere is an array. Nothing in the question is and nothing in this answer is. Where do arrays come into the discussion at all?

Comment: BenH comments: _"Not sure why $path is being treated as a **string array** rather than a string. But since it is, the + operator is adding another element to the array rather than concatenating."_

Comment: LotPing explains  _"my method of building the file name with the -format operator prevents mistreating $fn as a **string array**_

Comment: Oh...in that case I don't know where BenH came up with the idea that it was being treated as an array in the first place...

Comment: @EBGreen And because I get a `String` from the start, OP's script only fails with a file-does-not-exist (see my first comment), but succeeds if it is present, without fixing.

Comment: @EBGreen I think the assumpltion that the `+` was causing the $fn to become a string array. As we don't know the exact content of $path was and if probaply strange contents got lost pasting here it's IMO useless to speculate further without any input from OP.

Comment: I agree, I also started doubting whether the script in the question is exactly the same as being run by OP to result in the given error. I did ... only reason why my conclusions look weird here :/

Comment: @EBGreen My issue has to be something in my profile hence why I couldn't figure out why it was being treated as an array, but I got the same behavior as the asker but `-noprofile` fixes it. Still not sure what module is the offender.